# NuGet Package for Tuples in C#7 causes an error in my views

Tags: asp.net, c#-7.0

I am trying to use the new tuple features in C# 7 in an ASP.NET MVC 5 app, using .NET version 4.6.1. and Visual Studio 2017 RC. To do so I referenced this article here: [What's new in C# 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/), which said to install System.ValueTuple via NuGet. When I did this, the tuple syntax started working for me like in this example code:

```
public void TupleCaller()
{
   (var valOne, var valTwo) = TupleExample();
}

public (string, string) TupleExample()
{
    return ("Tuple Item One", "Tuple Item Two");
}
```

However, when I run the app, my views immediately throw this error:

> CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I have tried all of the following:

1. Adding a reference to System.Runtime Version 4.0 as the error says
2. Tried what was provided in this [C# 7.0 ValueTuple Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444981/c-sharp-7-valuetuple-compile-error) and in this [Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216740/c-sharp-7-features-dont-work-within-a-web-project-on-visual-studio-2017-rc) by installing the 2.0 Compilers.
3. Manually adding a reference to System.Runtime in the view (I think I was just getting a little desperate by that point).

As soon as I uninstall the System.ValueTuple NuGet package and comment out the new Tuple code, everything renders properly in the views like before.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I added the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` Nuget package (v1.0.3) to my project, and it works again!

Comment: This worked but I also needed to upgrade the Microsoft.Net.Compilers package to the latest version, otherwise it caused syntax errors when compiling

Comment: I also had to up the langversion from 6 to 7 in web.config i.e. <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />

Comment: Nuget package System.ValueTuple is needed

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to the other answers.

Remove System.valuetuple from references. Otherwise it doesn't work and I do not know why. Basically valuetuple is already in 4.7.2 and so if you use visual studio 2019 you're all set.

If you use visual studio 2019 and I did, that's what worked for me. I don't exactly know why. No need for nuget. No need to reference that directly.

[image]